# Facebook Marketing API: create Adcreative with Instagram Video

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

I want to create an ad based on an existing Instagram-Video post. Therefore I already uploaded the video to the /advideos endpoint.
However, now I'm stuck with creating the adcreative. The documentation doesn't give information on how to add the ID of the uploaded video as a parameter to the /adcreative call.

Any suggestions?

This is what my code looks like:

```js
FB.api(
  '/act_2757146414569266/adcreatives',
  'POST',
  {"object_id":"<PAGE_ID>","instagram_user_id":"<IG USER ID>","source_instagram_media_id":"<SRC_MEDIA_ID>","video_data":"{"video_id": "<UPLOADED VIDEO ID>"}"},

  function(response) {
      ...
  }
);
```

This is what I get back:

```js
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid parameter",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 1815279,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "Instagram video must be uploaded to Facebook",
    "error_user_msg": "If you want to promote an existing Instagram video, you need to upload it to Facebook first before creating the ad.",
    "fbtrace_id": "AfjvS_BshLJ8P3KlAB2EvJg1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you upload the video to Facebook like the error message say?

Comment: Yes as mentioned. I did so using the /advideos endpoint and got back the ID of the uploaded video.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you ever figure it out?